# SELECT records based on return of COUNT query

Tags: postgresql-9.2, count

I would like to create a query that returns records if values in a column occur more than once.  I came across other Stack Exchange questions but these only dealt with returning the number of occurrences and not the actual records.
For example, if I have a table of "Names":

```
Id   Name        City
1    Mike        NYC
2    Bob         DC
3    Rachel      DC
4    Mike        NYC
5    Bob         DC
6    Melissa     LA
7    Melissa     LA
```

...and I want to get the count of each name, I understand that I use the SQL:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS "Count"
FROM Names
GROUP BY Name;
```

The following would be returned:

```
Name       Count
Bob        2
Mike       2
Rachel     1
Melissa    2
```

Now, If I want to get the count of each name where the count is more than 1, I do this:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS "Count"
FROM Names
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1;
```

The following would be returned:

```
Name       Count
Bob        2
Mike       2
Melissa    2
```

Now, what I want to do is return all the columns for each value if they occur more than once.  I thought about doing a join on the table after doing the counts, but that seems like an expensive operation when I tried it a few times.  The more columns I added, I noticed that it was comparing those too, which is not what I want.  What I'd like is the result below.

```
Name       City    Count
Bob        DC        2
Mike       NYC       2
Melissa    LA        2
```

I know there should be an easy way to do this, but I'm just not finding it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a window function:

```
select name, city, cnt
from (
  select name, city, count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
  from names
) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks!  @a_horse_with_no_name.   That helps me a lot.  Are there any examples online of sample window functions?

Comment: @PuraVida: the manual has some examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Excellent!  I'll take a look.